# Consulta de paginación, recargar en una posición especifica

Tags: php, javascript, paginación

Buen dia, tengo una pagina tipo galería con una paginación a través de get. Cada vez que presiono el numero de la pagina a la que quiero ir recarga todo. Lo que desearía hacer es que en lugar que recargue al inicio, recargue en una posición de la página. ¿Me pueden ayudar por favor?

Comment: ¿Quieres decir, dentro de la página e independientemente del numero de página de la paginación que el foco este no al inicio de la página sino en otro punto?

Comment: claro, que al cambiar de página el foco no esté al inicio, como lo haria?

Answer (score 0):

#### Sobre anclas HTML

Para movernos a un punto específico en una página usamos "anclas", por ejemplo si abres la siguiente URL: https://www.ironwoods.es/blog#tools-editors vas a el punto de la página donde se ha situado el ancla para la página, en este caso a la sección "Herramientas - Editores".

Dentro del HTML se puede situar un ancha en un elemento específico mediante una ID, en la URL de ejemplo, el HTML es este:

`<h4 id="tools-editors">Herramientas - Editores</`h4>

Ahora puedes situar enlaces a este punto en cualquier punto de la página indicando en la URL el ancha:

```
<a href="#tools-editors" class="a b">Herramientas: editores</a>
```

O desde otras páginas, indicando el *ancla* al final de la URL: https://www.ironwoods.es/blog#tools-editors

Observa que el ancla usa el símbolo `#`.

---

#### Respuesta: anclas en paginación PHP

No puedo dar una respuesta específica sin conocer la implementación de la paginación... ¿usas algún sistema de rutas? ¿la función `header()`?
En este último caso, a la URL que se usa se añadiría el ancla específica, si puedes tener anchas diferentes que vas a asociar a la paginación tendrías que mantenerlas en sesión u otro mecanismo.